# Detection of non-ascii quotes

Tags: bash, ascii, zsh, quotes

Yet again I managed to cut and paste something from a source then execute that paste with modifications, but once again I had an error that made the issue truly opaque - the non-ascii double quotes were generated by the intermediary application that wanted to be "fancy", resulting in a derailed thought process for a few minutes while I studied the command line for the changes I made - which are usually the cause of problems.

Is there a script, terminal mode or some other solution that detects bash/zsh input and gives a nice clear error message if non-ascii input is detected in the command line? Granted, it will need an override, but the usual case is that non-ascii characters are not desired on the command line.

Comment: Does it not give a clear error when you try to run it?

Comment: [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) will do this for bash scripts, but not for commands issued at interactive prompts

Comment: One more vote for www.shellcheck.net, which is also available to install locally if you prefer.

Comment: Shellcheck isn't exactly what I was looking for, but it's good to know it's out there.